# Как изменять свойства объекта, который является аргументом функции?

Tags: javascript

Стоить задача, создать код объекта, где свойство firstName всегда undefined. Строчные значения свойств lastName и fullName изменяемые, например, пользователем. При вводе строчного значения свойства fullName, первое слово из этого свойства присваивается свойству firstName, вместо его значения undefined. Я код создал, но только значения объекта firstName, lastName, не изменяемые. Как мне их сделать изменяемые.

```js
const users = {
  firstName: undefined,
  lastName: 'Holy',
  fullName: 'Jack Holy',
}
for (let key in users) {
  if (users.firstName === undefined) {
    let name = users.fullName.split(' ');
    users.firstName = name[0];
  }
}

function restoreNames(users) {
  console.log(users.firstName)
}

restoreNames(users)
```

Comment: Уберите цикл `for (let key in users) {`. А вообще, от вас не этого ждут, скорее всего, а использование `setter`. Погуглите, что это такое.

Comment: @Yaant да, возможно, вы правы.